# Where do I go to ask some Linux/Chrome OS questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have some questions about Linux and [Chrome OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_OS). I want to ask questions about how to use Linux in [Chromebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromebook) and how to use its features. Where do I go to post those questions?

Comment: Did you try to [look this up](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux+chrome+os+stack+exchange)?

Answer (score 6):

For questions about Linux and Chrome OS, go to:

- [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

and tag the question with  [[chrome-os]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome-os) . It looks like you'll need the  [[chrome-book]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome-book)  tag too.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is https://superuser.com

Relevant tags:

- https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-os
- https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chromebook